# Facebook doesn't find iPhone app id while it's not published yet?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, app-store-connect, app-id

First of all, am I right, that this is an iPhone app id, that Facebook wants? I'm using the one from iTunes Connect page -> my app -> General Information -> Apple ID. This see the same ID in my url.

**My game is not published yet on app store and I want to test game requests.** At the moment, game requests are not being received and after some googling, turns out that I need this set up. When I input "iPhone store ID" in Facebook developer page, I get this error:

"This is not a valid iPhone Store ID. Please check the ID and try again".

What should I do?

Comment: You need to submit your app to Facebook so they give you a live version. By now, you may only check it works with FB testers' profiles.

Comment: FB tester profiles also don't receive these game requests, what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you could describe your problem a little more. Facebook testers are allowed to give the app permissions, interact with others... Maybe you're talking about something different: What are those requests? Are you referring to e.g. facebook invitations?

Comment: Sort if, I'm talking about these game requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the game is not on Facebook.com (unless I understood it wrong).

If you want to publish a game only on iOS, then you don't have access to the invitable_friends list in the Facebook Game Request API.

[image]

Comment: but according to this table, android only game should also not have game requests feature. However, it works perfectly fine on android build